# How to boost the performance of my own BSplineFunction

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, splines

In my `CAGD` package, I implemented a `CAGDBSplineFunction[]` like built-in `BSplineFunction[]`. Here is a performance comparison:

```
pts = Table[{ Cos[2 Pi u/6] Cos[v], Sin[2 Pi u/6] Cos[v], v}, {u, 6}, {v, -1, 1, 1/2}];
f = BSplineFunction[pts]
g = CAGDBSplineFunction[pts]

ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
ParametricPlot3D[g[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Obviously, my `CAGDBSplineFunction[]` is far slower(about 20**X**) than the built-in `BSplineFunction[]`

The `CAGDBSplineFunction[]` mainly uses an auxiliary function `functionalNonzeroBasis[]` to compute the coordinate of a parameter pair $(u,v)$.

To improve the performance, I refactor the `functionalNonzeroBasis[]` to `compiledNonzeroBasis[]`

```
searchSpan[{deg_, knots_}, u_] := 
  With[{un = knots[[-(deg + 1)]]}, 
   If[u == un, 
    Position[knots, un][[1, 1]] - 2, 
    Ordering[UnitStep[u - knots], 1][[1]] - 2
   ]
  ]

coeff[u_, U_, i_, p_] := 
 If[U[[i + p + 1]] != U[[i + 1]], 
   (u - U[[i + 1]])/(U[[i + p + 1]] - U[[i + 1]]), 0]

compiledNonzeroBasis= 
 ReleaseHold[
  Hold@Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {p, _Integer}, {u, _Real, 1}, {u0, _Real}}, 
   Module[
    {lst = Table[0., {p + 2}, {p + 1}], cc = i - 2},
    lst[[2, 1]] = 1.0;
    Do[
     lst[[m + n - cc, n + 1]] =
       coeff[u0, u, m, n] lst[[m + n - 1 - cc, n]] + (1 - 
          coeff[u0, u, m + 1, n]) lst[[m + n - cc, n]],
     {n, 1, p}, {m, i - n, i}
    ];
    lst // Transpose // Last // Rest
   ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ] /. DownValues[coeff]
]

compiledBSplineSurf[
  ctrlnets_, {{deg1_, knots1_}, {deg2_, knots2_}}, 
  u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{i, j, validnets, row, col},
  i = searchSpan[{deg1, knots1}, u];
  j = searchSpan[{deg2, knots2}, v];
  validnets = 
   Take[ctrlnets, {i - deg1 + 1, i + 1}, {j - deg2 + 1, j + 1}]; 
  row = compiledNonzeroBasis[i, deg1, knots1, u];
  col = compiledNonzeroBasis[j, deg2, knots2, v];
  row.Transpose[validnets, {1, 3, 2}].col
]
```

**Test**

```
(*knot vector*)
k1 = {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.333333, 0.666667, 1., 1., 1., 1.};
k2 = {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.5, 1., 1., 1., 1.};

ParametricPlot3D[
 compiledBSplineSurf[pts, {{3, k1}, {3, k2}}, u, v], 
 {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

This time the performance improves about 2**X**

[image]

Another trial is trying `` Compile`GetElement ``

```
With[{get = Compile`GetElement},
 basisCoeff[deg_, U_, i_, u_] :=
  If[U[[i + deg + 1]] != U[[i + 1]],
   (u - get[U, i + 1])/(get[U, i + deg + 1] - get[U, i + 1]),
   (*case for ui=uj*)
   0.0
  ]; 
optimizedNonzeroBasis = 
  ReleaseHold[
   Hold@Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {deg, _Integer}, {knots, _Real, 1}, {u0, _Real}}, 
    Module[{lst = Table[0., {deg + 2}, {deg + 1}], c = i - 2}, 
      lst[[2, 1]] = 1.0;
      Do[
        With[{mn = m + n}, 
         lst[[mn - c, n + 1]] = 
          basisCoeff[n, knots, m, u0] get[lst, mn - c - 1, n] + 
           (1 - basisCoeff[n, knots, m + 1, u0]) get[lst, 
          mn - c, n]
        ],
        {n, 1, deg}, {m, i - n, i}
      ];
      Rest@Last[Transpose[lst]
     ]
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ] /. DownValues[basisCoeff]]
 ]

ParametricPlot3D[
  optimizedBSplineSurf[pts, {{3, k1}, {3, k2}}, u, v], 
  {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

So I would like to know:

- Is it possible to **further** improve/boost the performance of `compiledBSplineSurf[]`?

---

**Update：**

For the `optimizedBSplineSurf[]`, just replace `compiledNonzeroBasis[]` with `optimizedNonzeroBasis[]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to fully compile your function:

```
fullycompiledBSplineSurf = 
  Hold@Compile[{{ctrlnets, _Real, 3}, {deg1, _Integer}, {deg2, _Integer}, 
                {knots1, _Real, 1}, {knots2, _Real, 1}, {u, _Real}, {v, _Real}}, 
      Module[{i, j, validnets, row, col}, 
        i = searchSpan[{deg1, knots1}, u];
        j = searchSpan[{deg2, knots2}, v];
        validnets = Take[ctrlnets, {i - deg1 + 1, i + 1}, {j - deg2 + 1, j + 1}];
        row = optimizedNonzeroBasis[i, deg1, knots1, u];
        col = optimizedNonzeroBasis[j, deg2, knots2, v];
        row.Transpose[validnets, {1, 3, 2}].col
      ], 
      CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
      "RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, 
      CompilationTarget -> C, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ] /. DownValues@searchSpan // ReleaseHold;

ParametricPlot3D[
  fullycompiledBSplineSurf[pts, 3, 3, k1, k2, u, v], 
  {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Now the function is about half as fast as the built-in:

```
ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

I think I don't need to make any explanation, because all the techniques above have been used in answering your previous questions.

Comment: Very fast! I think you should give a perfance comparison between `fullycompiledBSplineSurf []` and `BSplineFunction[]`

Comment: In addition, owing to I have no **C-compiler** on the current PC, I just use the "WVM", which also very [fast](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CM1ZD.png).

Comment: It is very strange to see that: although the `librarylinkNonzeroBasis[]` is faster than `optimizedNonzeroBasis[]`, `librarylinkBSplineSurf[] ` is not faster than `fullycompiledBSplineSurf[]`.